# Run cumulative total by multiple groups

Tags: r, cumulative-sum, cumsum

I have been given a large germination data set and need to calculate a running cumulative germination count by week. (Thanks in advance)

Example dataset

```
df <- read.table(text="
Treatment   Species     Temp    Week   Germination
 1 T1        A           5     1     1
 2 T1        A           5     2     2
 3 T1        A           5     3     3
 4 T2        A          10     1     3
 5 T2        A          10     2     2
 6 T2        A          10     3     1", header=TRUE)

#   Treatment Species  Temp  Week Germination
   <chr>     <chr>   <int> <int> <int>
 1 T1        A           5     1     1
 2 T1        A           5     2     2
 3 T1        A           5     3     3
 4 T2        A          10     1     3
 5 T2        A          10     2     2
 6 T2        A          10     3     1


Anticipated Oucome


 Treatment Species  Temp  Week Germination Cum_Germination
   <chr>    <chr>   <int>  <int>  <int>        <int>        
 1 T1        A           5     1     1       1
 2 T1        A           5     2     2       3
 3 T1        A           5     3     3       6 
 4 T2        A          10     1     3       3
 5 T2        A          10     2     2       5
 6 T2        A          10     3     1       6
```

Comment: `df %>% group_by(Species, Treatment) %>% mutate(Cum_Germination = cumsum(Germination))`